# How to change HybridWebView (iOS) Uri dynamically?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have a `HybridWebView` in my app and i need to change the uri dynamically (When the user click at some menu the uri changes), but it does not change at all... I use `WebView` and it works great, but when I use the `HybridWebView` the Uri is not changing.

This ContentView where is my HybridWebView is inside an AbsoluteLayout...

```
    <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                 x:Name="contentView">
            <local1:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView"/></ContentView>
```

This is the code behind (Where i handle the click on the menus to change the url, every click is a different content):

```
public async void ChangeURL() { hybridWebView.Uri = MyUrl; }
```

This is my HybridWebView class:

```
 public class HybridWebView : WebView
 {
    Action<string> action;
    
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(Uri),
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }

    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAction(string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(data);
    }

    public HybridWebView()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you share the code how to change the url for `HybridWebView`? In addition, you also could share the code of `HybridWebView`, it will be better to know the reason.

Comment: Hi, i added the code up there... Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad you have solved that. Remember to mark the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it like this:

protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

```
    if (Control.Url != null)
    {
        var idn = new System.Globalization.IdnMapping();
        var dotnetUri = new System.Uri(Element.Uri);
        _url = ((HybridWebView)Element).Uri;

        NSUrl nsUrl = new NSUrl(dotnetUri.Scheme, idn.GetAscii(dotnetUri.DnsSafeHost), dotnetUri.PathAndQuery);
        Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(nsUrl));
    }
}
```

I had to add the OnElementPropertyChanged to change the url dynamically by the CustomRenderer